# ¿Cómo puedo poner un logo entre el box de usuario y el de mensaje del chat?

Tags: html

Buenas lo dicho estoy editando un poco el chatbox de mi canal de twitch y querria ponerle un logo entre el box de usuario y el de mensaje adjunto imagen, quiero ponerlo justo en el circulo rojo que he marcado.

https://codepen.io/vance_dyer/pen/WNgPymY

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@700;900&display=swap);

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

body {line-height: 1.5em; color: #fff; -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 16%, left top, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));}

#log>div { position: relative; padding-top: 21px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
#log>div { animation: message .3s ease forwards, fadeOut 0.5s ease 15s forwards;}

.colon { display: none; }

#log {position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 0 10px 10px;}


/* ===== USERNAME ===== */
#log .meta {box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(9, 19, 20, 0.35); position: absolute; top: 0; left: 10px; padding: 9px 14px; line-height: 15px; z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu'; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 900;}
  #log .meta .badges {float: left; margin-right: 10px;}
    #log .meta .badges > img { width: 18px; height: 18px; margin-right: 5px;}
      #log .meta .badges > img:last-child {margin-right: 0;}
  #log .meta .name {float: left; line-height: 21px;}

/* ===== USERMESSAGE ===== */
 #log .triangulo{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 18px solid #C8FFFB;
border-right: 9px solid transparent;
border-left: 9px solid transparent;
float:right;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top:5px;
}

#log .message {position: relative; min-height: 20px;}
  #log .message .container-message {box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(9, 19, 20, 0.35); background: rgba(9, 19, 20, 0.75); padding: 20px 18px 15px 18px; border: 2px solid #C8FFFB; display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Roboto'; font-size: 18px; word-break: break-word;}
      #log .container-message::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -6px;
      border-top: 6px solid #C8FFFB;
      left: 0;
      border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    }
    
    
    #log .message .container-message .emote {background-image: none !important;}
    #log .message .container-message .emote img {max-width: 25px;}
@keyframes message {
  0% {
    max-height: 100vmax;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    max-height: 100vmax;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- item will be appened to this layout -->
<div class="top-degrade"></div>

<!-- item will be appened to this layout -->
<div id="log" class="sl__chat__layout"></div>

<!-- chat item -->
<script type="text/template" id="chatlist_item">
  <div data-from="{from}" data-id="{messageId}">
    <div class="meta" style="background-color: {color};">
      <span class="badges"></span>
      <span class="name">{from}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="message">


    
      <div class="container-message">
     
        {message}
        
      
         <div class="triangulo">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<div class="bottom-degrade"></div>
```

[image: Quiero ponerlo justo donde marco con el circulo rojo]

Comment: Hola, por favor no pongas trabajos en este sitio, este sitio es para preguntas y respuesta no para trabajar. Mejora tu pregunta  diciendo en que estas fallando o que error sale para que podamos ayudarte(Oviamente necesitas poner tu intento :)

Comment: Y otra pregunta: ¿Que biblioteca de plantillas usas?. [script type="text/template"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)

Comment: Porque no usas una imagen con posicion relativa al contenedor, que en este caso seria ese cuadro que estas marcando. con relativo me refiero que la imagen este dentro de ese contenedor, pero no en posicion fixed.  Sino en relative o absoluta. Y marca el porcentaje left deacuerdo al contenedor left:num%;

Comment: Buenas, primero que nada lo siento mucho tienes razón tendría que haber puesto el intento, estoy retomando esto y aún ando un poco verde lo siento.  Respecto a la librería de plantillas no se a que te refieres ya que el código no es todo mío, pero te dejo el código de JS si es a lo que te refieres // Please use event listeners to run functions.
document.addEventListener('onLoad', function(obj) {
 // obj will be empty for chat widget
 // this will fire only once when the widget loads
});

document.addEventListener('onEventReceived', function(obj) {
   // obj will contain information about the e

Comment: Hola, creo que la solucion está en usar float:left en css para la imagen. La imagen debe estar dentro del elemento que quieres al lado de la imagen: [Asi](https://codepen.io/dabl03/pen/RwYdgNL). Por ejemplo el caption es este div: <div class="caption">GodOfhuskies</div> entonces la imagen deberia estar a dentro de ese div: <div class="caption">GodOfhuskies<img src="direction you logo" class="logo"/></div> en css para esa imagen seria: .caption .logo{float:right}

Comment: @VanceDyler Cuando ejecutas esto solo consigues una pagina en blanco. Eso es porque tu codigo html esta dentro de un script que el navegador no conoce por lo que lo innora, ese script se deja como plantilla. Hay biblioteca que se encargan de agarrar esa plantilla, copiarla interpretarla y despues pegarla en la pagina web.

Comment: Hola dime, si mi solucion te ayudo para pasarlo de los comentario a una respuesta ; )

Comment: buenas Daniel gracias por la ayuda pero me sale el logo justo al lado del nombre de usuario, yo lo quiero transpasando una parte del cuadrado del nombre de usuario, no se si me explico.

Comment: 1 cuadro 1   logo asi?

Comment: Donde pones el 1 de la derecha ahí o sea que esté dentro y fuera del cuadrado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144908/discussion-between-daniel-briceno-and-vance-dyer).

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo puedes poner el nombre en un contenedor span y la imagen con el logo a fuera de ese `span`, modificarlo con css para agregarle las dimensiones al `span` y para que el logo quede medio fuera de la caja de nombre puedes moverlo con `transform:translate(x,y)` en css.

```css
.msg-container{
    padding-bottom:4px;
   background-color:blue;
   display:inline-block;/*importante. Esto hace que este contenedor no ocupe todo el largo de la pantalla:)*/
}
.caption span{/*Solo para simular lo que tu tienes.*/
    margin:0;
    padding-top:4px;/*Aqui modificamos el alto del limite superior.*/
    padding-bottom:4px;/*Parte inferior*/
    background-color:red;
}
/*Aqui coloco la imagen en la parte derecha de su contenedor padre.*/
.caption .logo{
    /*Mitad del ancho de la imagen.*/
    transform:translate(-10px,5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="msg-container">
  <div class="caption"><!--Aquí irá nuestro nombre y nuestro logo-->
    <span>Nooooombreeeelargoooooo &nbsp; &nbsp; </span><!--Los cuatros espacios en blancos(&nbsp;) son para darle mas espacio a la imagen:) --> 
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20210617/ourlarge/pngtree-logo-gratis-png-image_3466978.jpg" width="20px" class="logo"/><!--Imagen sacada de google-->
  </div>
  <div style="color:white;font-weight:Bold;"><center>Mensaje</center></div>
</div>
<div class="msg-container">
  <div class="caption"><!--Aquí irá nuestro nombre y nuestro logo-->
    <span>Nooooombreeeelargoooooo 2 &nbsp; &nbsp; </span><!--Los cuatros espacios en blancos(&nbsp;) son para darle mas espacio a la imagen:) --> 
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20210617/ourlarge/pngtree-logo-gratis-png-image_3466978.jpg" width="20px" class="logo"/><!--Imagen sacada de google-->
  </div>
  <div style="color:white;font-weight:Bold;"><center>Mensaje 2</center></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="msg-container">
  <div class="caption"><!--Aquí irá nuestro nombre y nuestro logo-->
    <span>Corto-nombre &nbsp; &nbsp; </span><!--Los cuatros espacios en blancos(&nbsp;) son para darle mas espacio a la imagen:) --> 
    <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20210617/ourlarge/pngtree-logo-gratis-png-image_3466978.jpg" width="20px" class="logo"/><!--Imagen sacada de google-->
  </div>
  <div style="color:white;font-weight:Bold;"><center>Mensaje</center></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, he intentado poner lo que tu me dijiste toda la noche y sigue sin darme resultado.

Comment: te dejo el codigo que he implementado con tu ayuda https://codepen.io/vance_dyer/pen/VwGRMXa  y la imagen de como se ve: https://ibb.co/PTXFkyZ

Comment: ¿Lo necesitas para mañana?, si es así te ayudo hoy, de lo contrario mañana intentaré trabajar usando tu código

Comment: nono tranquilo, cuando puedas no hay fecha límite, gracias por la ayuda :)